# Drop down menu styling issue

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, nav

My drop down menu on my navigation bar is called "Works". I can't seem to figure out why "Works" has a grey box surrounding the word while the other words on the navigation bar do not.

[image: navbar example]

My CSS for the nav bar and drop down menu:

nav {

```
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 30px;
line-height: 1.5em;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

nav a, .dropbtn {

```
display: inline;
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px; 
font-family:"mrs-eaves";
```

}

.dropdown {

```
overflow: hidden;
```

}

.dropdown {

```
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 25px;    
border: none;
outline: none;
color: black;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: "mrs-eaves";
margin: 0;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

nav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus 
{

```
background-color: rgb(247, 219, 255);
```

}

.dropdown-content {

```
display: none;
position: relative;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
```

}

.dropdown-content a {

```
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: center;
```

}

.show {

```
display: block;
```

Here is my html:

```
<nav>
<center>
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Works
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="drawing.html">Drawing</a>
      <a href="animation.html">Animation</a>
      <a href="design.html">Design</a>
    </div> 
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="links.html">Links</a>
</center>
</nav>
```

Comment: could you please add html too.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard button style. So, if you want it to be transparent, you should add certain styling for your button class (.dropbtn).
It is,

```
.dropbtn {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it must be a button, add the following CSS

```
.dropbtn {
background: none;
border: none;
}
```

Then, in your CSS where you set the hover color, change it to this

```
nav a:hover, .dropdown:hover, .dropbtn:focus, .dropbtn:hover {
background-color: rgb(247, 219, 255);
}
```

Edit:

Added cursor change so its a pointer for consistency when the button is hovered.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsk8r1qL/19/)**